# integrate quick books data into asp.net application using web connector

Tags: quickbooks, qbwc

•   I am using asp.net . I have to integrate quick books data into my asp.net application.

•   In silverlight application using com objects  am able to connect to QB and getting the data from that By selecting Company name from .

•   But I have to do  all this stuff from the iis. So using com objects it is not possible to get the data com object.

So I have chosen Web connector.

My requirement  is :

1. I  will select the company database from User interface
2. After that I have to get the data like : customers ,vendors.
3. That data I have to import into my database.

But using Web Connector : that has different scenario…

1. I have to select first .qwc file using this we are calling web services. From there we will get the data.

Is it possible to call the web connector through the coding…..calling web service from there…

Or  is there any other solutions  without  selecting .qwc file

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to call the webconnector through the coding

No, the Web Connector calls *your* web service, not the other way around.

It can be scheduled to poll your web service every X minutes.

> Or is there any other solutions without selecting .qwc file

To use the Web Connector, you go through a one-time setup process of installing the .QWC file. You only have to do that *once*. After you've done that, there's nothing else necessary on the end-user side of things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Let me know is this correct way to  using web connector for my requirement.